# C++:Dereferencing a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

For instance, consider the variable declaration: `string* a`, if I do `std::cout << *a`, then is the program possible crash? I am thinking the memory of the pointer `a` is pointing to might be a bad memory. If yes, what is the **"Bad Memory"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a sure thing that it'll necessarily crash. For example, the memory that pointer references could end up being within a page of memory your program has permissions to read from. In that case, the program won't crash outright via a [segfault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Segmentation_fault_and_access_violation), this is why you call it "bad memory," or "garbage memory." It could end up printing gibberish, depending on the proximity of a null terminator, but it's basically undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`is the program possible crash?` -> yes it **should** segfault if a doesn't refer to memory allowed to your process.

Comment: "It **will** segfault" is quite a strong assumption. It is free to do anything else.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the term "segfault"?

Comment: Here is an example of where no segfault occurs, but instead an illegal instruction is attempted to be executed: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5a4526850551d56.

Answer (score 1):

If you only declare the pointer and never initialise it, then its address could contain any arbitrary value. Often, that means it's either not a valid address at all, or it's an address which your program isn't allowed to read and/or write. Attempting to dereference such a pointer can be an illegal operation, so typically your program will crash, and the OS will report an access violation or similar.

In theory, the pointer could also end up with a valid address which your program can access. It almost certainly won't contain meaningful data though, so anything you access through it will be nonsense.

Comment: "If you only declare the pointer and never initialise it, then its address could contain any arbitrary value." Can I understand this as if I do `string* a`, I will have that kind of probability to get an address that my program isn't allowed to read and /or write? Then it will crash.

Comment: if by any chance (or not) the adress refers to your process memory, it can corrupt the process, and the mistake is really hard to find. Else, an error will occur, and the process should be killed. If you run the process with root rights, it will not crash, but represents risks for others process.

Comment: @FlowerFire: You're correct -- an uninitialised (or 'wild') pointer will *usually* be invalid for your program. It doesn't matter even if it's a valid address though; you still shouldn't use it. You must **always** assign a valid address to a pointer before you try to read/write through it. Typically, that means declaring a `new` object/array, or getting the address of some existing data.